# Loop in assembly x8086 without labels

Tags: loops, assembly, cpu-registers

I am trying to make a code that duplicates itself to another location, and one of my commands is a loop command. the problem is that the loop's labels is not moving with the code itself. Is there an easy(and the most short) way to use registers to save the location where i want to loop.

i am not allowed to use variables and the cmp command.

Comment: `loop` and conditonal jumps use relative addressing, they are thus inherently position independent and can be duplicated at will.

Comment: But if you want to use unconditional jump instructions, then you have to count the numbers of bytes between the jump instruction itself and the destination address of the jump instruction, for calculating the destination address of the new jump instruction.

Comment: `loop` is always a `jmp short`. Conditional jumps (`jcc`) are `jmp short` or `jmp near`. Unconditional jumps can be `jmp far`.